# Adding Google In-App Billing causes app to not find Google Play Services

Tags: android, google-play-services, in-app-billing, google-cloud-messaging

My app uses `Google Cloud Messaging` and using the implementation code on the Android website, it checks if the `Google Play Services APK` is installed or not:

```
// Check for Google Play Services APK. If success, proceed with GCM registration.
public void registerGcm() {
    if (checkPlayServices()) {
        mGcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(mContext);
        mGcmRegId = getRegistrationId(mContext);

        if (mGcmRegId.isEmpty()) { new RegisterGCMTask().execute(); }
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Google Play Services APK not found\n"
                + "Please download Google Play Services", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mActivity.finish();
    }
}
```

Everything was working fine and `checkPlayServices()` returned true before. But once I implemented `v3 Google In-App Billing` as the instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html), it stopped working and `checkPlayServices()` started returning false.

Why is this happening? And has anyone else experienced similar problems? This error occurred after I upgrade Google Play Services.

I also getting this note in my Logcat as well:

```
08-19 13:12:39.730: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(11708): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 5089000 but found 5084036
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are few links that may help you understand resolve the issue:

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#ensure

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html#SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED